# Refused to load script because it violates Content Security Policy directive

Tags: aura, iframe, cors

I'm currently working to include my external js in aura component. So, i have included my external JS as static resource. but i'm getting the below exception.

> Refused to load the script '...' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'nonce-...' chrome-extension: 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'

[image: Refused to load script]

I have added all the required sites in below modules.

1. Cors
2. Remote Site Settings
3. CSP trusted sites.

Please guide me to handle this issue

My sample external JS code:

```
var contentURL= 'https://xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxx';
var serverUrl = 'https://xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxx';
var hostedJsUrl = 'https://xxxxxx.xx.xxxx.xxx';
var hostedJsPath = 'https://client.qa.xxxxxx.xxxxxx/qa/client-injected-latest';
var element = window.document.createElement('script');
element.setAttribute('id', 'letznav-script');
element.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
element.setAttribute('data-server', serverUrl);
element.setAttribute('data-instanceid', tenantKey);
element.setAttribute('data-hosted-js', hostedJsUrl);
element.setAttribute('data-content-url', contentURL);
element.setAttribute('src', hostedJsPath + '/apty-client.js');
element.setAttribute('data-fonts-url', fontsUrl);
window.document.head.appendChild(element);
```

Locker Service Results:

[image]

Comment: Salesforce blocks JavaScript code that violates common security rules so **many** 3rd party JavaScript libraries will not run. In the image you post 'unsafe-eval' is listed; read about that e.g. here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571401/why-exactly-is-eval-evil.

Comment: @KeithC Thanks for looking in to this but we are not using eval() in any calls in the js and even i have deactivated the lockerservice for my component. Could you please look in to this

Comment: OK. Have you tried adding a copy of the JS as a static resource and accessing it from there?

Comment: Currently i'm accessing my js through a static resource

Comment: The URLs in the error message look like they are external; does the static resource JS reference other external JS?

Comment: Yes i have added my external js code. Please check the updated question

Comment: @Pavantej Keith has already pointed you in the right direction. To state it more explicitly, while you may have included the external JS as static resource, does that external JS reference other external JS files which are hosted outside Salesforce? Try adding those also to static resources or whitelisting those JS files.

Comment: @arut Thanks for looking in to this i have debugged all the details and my external JS not referencing any other external JS files

Comment: I can see _contentURL_, _serverUrl_, _hostedJsUrl_, _hostedJsPath_ etc. in the sample external JS code posted. Are all of these added to CSP Trusted sites? Also, the external JS code seems to be creating a `<script>` element dynamically. Have you used [Locker Service Console](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/locker-service-console) to evaluate this JS code?

Comment: Yes i have added all the urls to CSP, cros, remote site settings too. And i have added my locker service console results. @arut

Comment: You will probably need to add other external JS files also as static resources. Adding their domain URL to CSP trusted sites probably won't cut it for JS resources.

Comment: Locker Service Console didn't give you the error because it's evaluating only the JS and not the URLs being used in the JS code. So, it is considering the JS to load something from within static resources in the org.

Answer (score 4):

You will have to tweak your external JS, load the other referenced JS files also as static resources and include them in aura component using `ltng:require`.

Refer to [CSP Overview](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.lightning.meta/lightning/security_csp.htm)

> JavaScript libraries can only be referenced from your org. All external
> JavaScript libraries must be uploaded to your org as static resources.
> The script-src 'self' directive requires script source be called from
> the same origin.

SF objective here is to help prevent cross-site scripting (XSS) and other code injection attacks

Your external JS file is trying to create a script tag and add it dynamically to `window.document.head`. During page rendering, `element.setAttribute('src', hostedJsPath + '/apty-client.js');` will possibly translate into `script-src` tag at page level. Adding the URL to CSP will not allow you to fiddle with `script-src` tag and that will always be set to ***self*** by default. As mentioned in [CSP Trusted Sites access to 3rd Party APIs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.lightning.meta/lightning/csp_trusted_sites.htm), only the few other tags are supported.

> When you define a CSP Trusted Site, you can add the site’s URL to the
> list of allowed sites for the following directives in the CSP header.
>
> connect-src, frame-src, img-src, style-src, font-src, media-src

For understanding the differences between `connect-src` & `script-src`, you may refer [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/connect-src) & [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src).

Comment: How does one get around this CSP for Experience Cloud sites? Same or different way?